# How to write this query with pivot table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am using the below query using pivot table.

i have year column and employee id column in one table

```
Select [2013],[2014],Cast(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),(CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),([2014]-[2013]))/CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),[2013])*100.00))as Varchar(50))+'%'AS Diff From
(Select [2013],[2014]
from
( Select Year,Count(EmployeeId)Cont from employee group by year) as sourcetable
Pivot ( sum(Cont) for [Year] in ([2013],[2014])) as pivotable )As A
```

i want the output as follows i.e last two years as columns and count as the value

```
2013   2014

------   -----------

50       100
```

I am able to achieve this but i had to hard code 2013, 2014 in pivot. Can i get dynamically like

if the years present in table are 2011, 2012 then the out put should be like below

```
2011   2012

------   -----------

75       150
```

or if the years present in table are 2015, 2014 then

```
2015   2014

------   -----------

40      80
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [dynamic Pivot](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/) which get column and create it, like

[2nd link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/) for understanding

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','')
       + QUOTENAME(Course)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Course FROM #CourseSales) AS Courses

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic
SET @DynamicPivotQuery =
  N'SELECT Year, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #CourseSales
    PIVOT(SUM(Earning)
          FOR Course IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```